# Customized error messages for $httpProvider.interceptors

Tags: javascript, angularjs, user-interface

We have implemented the below

```
function Inteceptors($httpProvider) {
    'ng-inject';
    $httpProvider.interceptors.push('ErrorInterceptor');
    $httpProvider.interceptors.push('LoadingInterceptor');
}

function ErrorInteceptor($q, MyNotificationService) {
    'ng-inject';

    return {
        responseError: function(response) {
            var msg = JSON.stringify(response.data);
            var status = response.status;
            console.log('in ErrorInterceptor', response);
            if (response.status === -1) {
                status = null;
                msg = 'An unspecified error occured while trying to make a request'
            }
            var notification = {
                type: 'error',
                status: status,
                msg: msg
            };
            MyNotificationService.add(notification);
            return $q.reject(response);
        }
    };
}
```

This allow errors like 404 and 500 to be intercepted and a message is being prompted to the users.

However, there are certain circumstances that I would like to make use of my own customized error message.

For example when I have a function that makes a call to an API:

```
    this.list = function() {
        return $http({
                method: 'GET',
                url: myendpoint
            })
            .then(function(response) {
                    return response.data;
                },
                function(err) {
                    return [];
                });
    }
```

The response looks like the below in case of 404:

```
- Object
  -- config: Object
- data: Object
- headers: (name)
  - status: 404
  - statusText: "Not Found"
- __proto__: Object
```

so if the API returns 404, right now the interceptor is displaying response.data which is "Not found" and status is 404 in response.status

So the message now is

```
(404) {"detail": "Not found"}
```

And that is ugly and not helpful!

I would like to provide my own customized messages, how would I achieve that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly then you want to return custom error from `ErrorInteceptor()` function. You are getting this same error because you are returning `response` i.e. `return $q.reject(response);` So try to return your custom message from your service.

Try this

```
 return {
        responseError: function(response) {
            var status = response.status;
            console.log('in ErrorInterceptor', response);
            if (response.status === -1) {
                status = null;
                msg = 'An unspecified error occured while trying to make a request'
            }
            var notification = {
                type: 'error',
                status: status,
                msg: msg
            };
            MyNotificationService.add(notification);
            return $q.reject(response.statusText);// this is what you should return
        }
    };
```

Comment: hey @sourabh, thanks. I have other functions that calls API which will return some other 500 errors, for example, so they are different messages, and I want the ErrorInteceptor() to handle that but then in certain calls to API when error occurs, I would like to provide my own custom messages.

Comment: hey @sourabh, i added how the response looks like in my question, and using var errorMsg = JSON.parse(response); I get error SyntaxError: Unexpected token u in JSON at position 0 at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)